# "‘python’: No such file or directory" when running Python file as executable

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have installed python and I have a file Wifite.py that exists in my current directory.

But whenever I try to run the Wifite2.py file I receive this error:

> ‘python’: No such file or directory

```
jarvus@jarvus:~/wifite2$ ls
bin          PMKID.md             setup.py   wordlist
Dockerfile   README.md            tests      wordlist-
EVILTWIN.md  reaver-wps-fork-t6x  TODO.md
LICENSE      runtests.sh          wifite
MANIFEST.in  setup.cfg            Wifite.py


jarvus@jarvus:~/wifite2$ ./Wifite.py
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

What changes should be made to get `./Wifite.py` working?

The workaround I got is using:

```
python3 Wifite.py
```

But I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: try `python Wifite2.py`

Comment: try using `python3 Wifinite2.py`, it seems that you have some misconfiguration between python2 and python3

Comment: How did you install Python? It seems that `env` can't find it in your default `PATH`. If you installed it through `sudo apt install python3` or similar, that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python-is-python3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This message:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

suggests that the [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in your script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Since running the script explicitly with `python3` worked OK, it sounds like you're on a distro where by default you only have `python3` and no `python`. As other answers suggest, you may install `python-is-python3` (which basically creates a `python` symlink pointing to `python3`). If you don't wish to do that, then just adjust the script's hashbang so that `/usr/bin/env` looks for `python3`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: Thanks, mate, what I ended up doing was changing the hashbang to 
"/usr/bin/env python" to "/usr/bin/env python3" in my python file and it solved the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468590/env-python-no-such-file-or-directory-when-building-app-with-xcode
Helpful answer.

Comment: `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python` Use this

Answer (score 2):

Seems you don't have `python2` installed but only `python3` but it is not registered as plain `python`.
Try

```
which python
which python2
which python3
```

If only the last command runs without error you can try to link python3 to python with

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

Comment: Don't. If it's `python3`, then use `python3` (in the shebang, when running scripts, ex). The OS may rely on `python` being an actual Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use [shebangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))!
In the first line of your script write the python interpretor path.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

Then chmod +x your file on shell. That will make it executable. And you can directly run it.

Comment: The shebang can also be `/usr/local/bin/python3` (or whatever is the output of `which python3`) if that is what is available on the system.

Comment: Yes it can. Any interpreter you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `python3 Wifite2.py` from the directory where the file exists.

Comment: yes I got that working using this command but is there a way to get it working without passing the python command

Comment: No. Basically you are expecting your os to guess what to do with the file called "Wifite2.py". You could `python3 Wifite2.py`, you could `vim Wifite2.py` etc. If you want to run the script, you must specify it.

Comment: @Yuv_c in Unix-like systems, [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) tells the OS exactly what program it should use to interpret the file. OP does have one in the script, as can be seen from the error message. Not having a shebang and still trying to execute the script like this is another story though - in that case the OS does indeed have to guess what to execute the script with, AFAIK its guess is usually `/bin/sh`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that @Czaporka. Thanks for the explanation.