# env: python: No such file or directory when building app with Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, nativescript

When I build/run/archive my app in Xcode (on MacOS 12.3) I encounter this error:

```
env: python: No such file or directory
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I think I might have changed something with regard to my python environment while working on a school project or messed something up there. However, I can not figure out what is wrong.

I tried reinstalling Xcode and python (using brew and pyenv). I also relinked python using brew. But I still encounter the same error.

Which python gives the following results:

```
which python3
-> /usr/local/bin/python3
```

And in my ~/.zshrc I have the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH
```

Any help would be appreciated! If I missed or forgot anything please let me know, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Are you sure that what's in .zshrc affects Xcode? I don't *know*, but I would not bet on it, as Xcode is not normally launched from a shell.

Comment: Yes I don't think that should matter. However I added it as I'm quite new and normally I run the NativeScript project in the terminal (which uses Xcode), so I thought that might be affected by it. But indeed, also running it in Xcode also triggers this error.

Answer (score 91):

Homebrew only installs the binary `python3`, just to be safe. Xcode is complaining about a lack of the binary `python` (note the lack of a 3!).

You have a couple of options:

1. When installing `python3`, Homebrew also creates a `libexec` folder with unversioned symlinks, such as `python` (what you're missing). Note the Caveats printed when installing it:

   ```
   $ brew info python
   python@3.9: stable 3.9.10 (bottled)
   ==> Caveats
   Python has been installed as
     /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

   Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
   `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
     /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin

   See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
   ```

   You could add this directory to your `$PATH`, such that `python` and `pip` become available; something like the following might suffice:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH="'"$(brew --prefix)"'/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:$PATH"' \
      >>~/.bash_profile
   ```

   ... although that will need to be modified according to your precise version of Python3, your shell of choice, etc.
2. Alternatively and more simply, although a little more jankily, you could simply manually create the appropriate symlinks:

   ```
   ln -s "$(brew --prefix)/bin/python"{3,}
   ```

Comment: Can't work on MacBook Air m1. Please refer to https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/15510

Comment: Awesome, #1 didn't work for me even though I have 3.9, but #2 did.

Comment: @劉大為 I'm not sure what you mean — the above works precisely as it's supposed to on an M1; that's what I'm typing on, right now. That's why the snippets use `brew --prefix`, in fact. That said, modifying $PATH is difficult to explain predictably; there's lots and lots of variance on different systems as to how the final value comes into existence — if it didn't work, I suggest you dive into debugging your $PATH settings.

Comment: I've been stuck for few hours until I ran the above command. Worked great on M1 macbook pro.

Comment: second alternative works

Comment: and if you are using mac ports `sudo port select --set python python311` or `sudo port select --set python python310`

Answer (score 34):

Add `-f` to be effective.

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this worked, be sure to add 'sudo' before this command if you're in macOS monterey

Comment: worked for me without sudo!

Comment: it work. thank you

Answer (score 21):

I had posted the same question on [nativescript official github](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9833) and the solution that worked for me was in the answer by the user shilik

> Monterey 12.3 removes python 2. All you need to do is to reinstall
> python2 back to system from this link
> https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/

Comment: @aaossa I have removed the "question part" of my previous post: was intended to give only a little bit of (my) context to the original question because I think that was the same problem. Now I left only the answer, did you mean this in your comment?

Comment: Upgrading to Monterey messed me up too. This is what I did... 1) Install pyenv with `brew install pyenv`
2) Install Python 2.7 with `pyenv install 2.7.18` and then `pyenv global 2.7.18`
3) Then set the default paths typing in the console `export PATH="${HOME}/.pyenv/shims:${PATH}"`

Comment: @tyborg You are the man / or gal ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 21):

1. install python3
2. run 'ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python',Create a link to Python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked for me on Monterey!
`ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: @bibo bode - this gives me 'Permission denied'

Comment: You may have to use `sudo` before the command @Robbie

Answer (score 11):

For me the problem was with missing python
`env: python: No such file or directory`

BUT in the end ***missing was python version 2.x*** after updating to macOS Monterey 12.5 (21G72).
Problem was resolved by installing python from:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/

What I've also tried but you probably don't have to do:

- `sudo brew install python`
- `sudo brew upgrade`
- `sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`
- `sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python`
- `sudo ln -s $(which python3) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python`
- `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Thanks! "sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python" helped me

Answer (score 4):

This took me days of head scratching, and none of the solutions I found on the internet worked.

Eventually what DID work for me was this:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python
```

I used the find command to find all instances of python in the file hierarchy:

```
find / -name python*
```

and I saw that there was a symbolic link labelled `python3` in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/` that was linked to a python instance deep within the bowels of Xcode.

However there was no symbolic link labelled `python` which seems to be what Xcode is looking for.

So I created a symbolic link linking `python` to `python3` and that did the trick.

For what it's worth, I installed python via pyenv which I installed through homebrew on a 2020 Mac mini M1.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, created symbolic link for dev_appserver.py like below.

```
ln -s /opt/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python
ln -s /opt/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python2
```

Command location and version should be adapted to your environment.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue with the above-mentioned answers.

In my case, while I was trying `npm install` in my node project and was facing this issue.

**Note:** `% brew install python` is a prerequisite for all the below steps! Test if python is correctly installed by `brew info python`

1. First thing which comes to mind is if python is correctly installed and the path is set correctly.

> `python --version` was giving `zsh - python not found error` while `python3 --version` was a success.

2. Next steps were to set the correct path. I did the below steps and it worked:

> - `echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc`
> - `ln -s -f "$(brew --prefix)/bin/python"{3,}`
> - `ln -s -f "$(which python3)"{3,}`

What I was missing was to run `brew install python`, and it *worked like a charm*!